# RHEV Hypervisor - 3.2 Network (IPv4)

Tags: virtualization, virtualhost, kvm

During RHEV Hypervisor 3.2 Installation, by mistake I selected Network (eth0) as Dynamic and also provided IP, Subnet and Getway. Actually wanted to setup Static with the specified IP, Subnet and Default Gateway. Now it is not allowing me to change to Static from Dynamic.

Is there any method to alter the eth0 IPv4 settings from Dynamic to static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to change the network configuration, you should go to the Host main tab select the 'Network Interfaces' sub tab then press the 'setup network' button.
A new dialog should pop and there you need to choose the network which you want to change, hover on the network and press the small pencil, then you get a dialog where you can change the network configuration details (including the boot protocol).

Comment: Thanks livnat for your quick and positive reply! I have resolved with your solution. Many thanks. :)